# searching a string in IRC logs

Tags: google-search

I want to search for a specific string in all the IRC logs @ https://www.yoctoproject.org/irc/index.html, can you tell me how to do this.

Comment: URLs have same syntax: https://www.yoctoproject.org/irc/%23yocto.<year>-<month>-<day>.log.html
you can try a simple script wich will navigate into those pages and search for a string into it

Comment: can you share link for any sample script. I am trying for a search  string to place in google search bar.

Comment: just a simple python script would make it:
make a for loop in a for loop for the month and day, year won't change, and in each iteration, get the content of webpage and do a regex match.
I don't know such scripts on the web so I guess you'll need to write it by yourself.